# How to pass custom error message in django_filters fields?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am using django_filter package for custom filtering in my django rest framework API,
Below is the given code

```
import django_filters
from src.core.models.rough_management import DocumentDetails


class DocumentDetailsFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    my_date = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentDetails
        fields = ['my_date']
```

Here i am getting **"Enter a valid date"** as an exception message when i enter invalid date range so my question is how to pass custom exception message to **"No records found"**?

Answer (score 1):

Django filters use native django form fields to validate data.
`DateFromToRangeFilter` use `django.forms.fields.DateField`.
([Django DateField code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/da02cbd1effc951b14c981925d0e26a39566649e/django/forms/fields.py#L463))

You need to implement your own custom filter with little changes.

**Not that** from my perspective it's bad practice because that code interferes `DateField` error which should return default error as it is "Enter a valid date" and it's good information from api if you enter invalid date value like text "abcd".

Anyway for now i don't see better place to implement that and that is simpler than interference in `FilterSet` class.

You can also look on original code [here](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/2c81768188cd4ce65d5fd20919ea4a8b2b5f214b/django_filters/filters.py#L501) to see how it's designed.

```
class CustomDateField(django.forms.fields.DateField):
    default_error_messages = {
        "invalid": "No records found",
    }

class CustomDateRangeField(RangeField):
    widget = DateRangeWidget

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = (CustomDateField(), CustomDateField()) # Important change here only
        super().__init__(fields, *args, **kwargs)

    def compress(self, data_list):
        # Compress method stay the same as it is in original code
        if data_list:
            start_date, stop_date = data_list
            if start_date:
                start_date = handle_timezone(
                    datetime.combine(start_date, time.min), False
                )
            if stop_date:
                stop_date = handle_timezone(
                    datetime.combine(stop_date, time.max), False
                )
            return slice(start_date, stop_date)
        return None


class CustomDateFromToRangeFilter(RangeFilter):
    field_class = CustomDateRangeField
```